Exiting / cancel rest of the Promise handling
I was reading some posts and got similar question in interview. Lets say the code snippet looks like this:
const newPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject());

newPromise
  .then(() => { console.log("1") })
  .catch((error) => { console.log("2"); })
  .then(() => { 
      console.log("3"); 
      throw new Error; 
  })
  .then(() => console.log("4"))
  .catch(() => console.log("5"))
  .catch(() => console.log("6"))

So by looking at this, my first thought was that since the Promise "instantly" rejects, it will look for the closest catch, handle the "error" and exit the Promise cycle.
As it turns out there are 2 scenarious what can happen after that catch method:

If it handles the error or you call Promise.resolve(), then the Promise switches back to fullfilled state and it will look for the first then method.
If it rethrows the errors or you call Promise.reject() it will propogate the error, promise stays in the rejection state and it will look for the closest catch method.

So my question is - how can we simple exit / terminate the Promise process from either then or catch callbacks, if we end up in this "callback hell" scenario?
What I tried:
Without returning anything, it goes to fulfill state, which means nearest then is executed.
Then I tried to simply return any value, it results in Promise going in to "fulfill" state.
Then I tried either Promise.reject() or Promise.resolve() - same result as above respectively.

your first catch (as do the second and third) handles the error, and returns a resolved promise - this is the benefit of chaining, as it does allow intermediate "rejections" to be handled in some way without rejecting the whole chain ... if you want the first catch to terminate the chain, you need to either throw or return a rejected promise - note: since .then and .catch return a Promise, you most likely never to return Promise.resolve - also, throw is very much like return Promise.reject() inside .then/.catch (note the return in that statement)

it will look for the first then method is not exactly correct - read this to get a better understanding of Promise chains - it's not mentioned in the link, but .catch(onRejected) is exactly the same as .then(null, onRejected) ... in fact, in all Promise libraries (before promises were built-in to javascript, .catch was just Promise.prototype.catch = function(cb) { return this.then(null, cb);};

NB: there is no "callback hell" here.

You can't "cancel" a promise chain.  It will go to the next .then() or .catch() in the chain, no matter what (depending upon the promise state).  If it resolves and there's no subsequent .then(), then nothing else will execute, but if there is a .then(), there is no way to stop it from executing that.  If it rejects and there is no subsequent .catch(), then you will have an unhandled promise rejection which is a no-no.  If you really have to skip subsequent .then() handling, then you can resolve with a sentinel value or state that all subsequent .then()  handlers check for.

I do not think this is true - " if you want the first catch to terminate the chain, you need to either throw or return a rejected promise", taking in mind the scenario that I showed above, where after the catchmethod there are more chain methods, both then and catch. @JaromandaX

Well, maybe not the best example, since I dont return these console.logs, but in real world scenario the pattern would be the same, where for example, I returrn async code stuff -> then(() => asyncOperation()).then((resFromAsyncOp) => otherAsyncOp).then(dataFromOtherAsyncOp => ......, and to my knowledge its called as callback hell. Correct me if I am wrong @trincot

Thanks for straight forward answer @jfriend00

@digital - perhaps my explanation is not clear enough, your comment suggests you do not understand me

Hmm, all I wanted to understand is whether I can cancel the rest of the Promise chain, if for example I encounter and handle the error in the first catch block. I re-read your answers, they make sense, but that one sentence I quoted does not make sense to me, because there is no way to terminate the chain, you either fulfill and move forward to next then or reject/re-throw and move to closest catch, if they exist (as in my og question example). @JaromandaX

oh, yeah, you can't terminate the chain, that's true, but effectively your code in the catch ensures that the following then (onFullfilled) is called

Yep, yep, thats correct and thanks for your time helping me learn! @JaromandaX

Definitely not what you want, but for the sake of it, you can "interrupt" the chain by returning a never resolving Promise in the callback you want to block from. e.g. .catch(err => new Promise(()=>{})). But don't do this!. Instead handle the error clearly. If your catch block did not handle the error in a way the operation is not a failure anymore, it should be propagated further down as an error, so throw/reject from the catch block.

Yep, got it! @Kaiido


my first thought was that since the Promise "instantly" rejects, it will look for the closest catch, handle the "error" and exit the Promise cycle.

Execution cannot directly jump to the closest catch method callback. The rejection of the original promise has to go through the entire chain, i.e., if you have then method calls in between the original promise and the first catch method call in the promise chain, the promises returned by each then method will be rejected one after the other with the same rejection reason as the original promise.
Consider the following code example:


Promise.reject("original error")
.then(console.log, (error) => console.log("then rejection callback,", error))
.catch(console.log)



Note that the catch method is called on the promise returned by the then method, and not the promise returned by the Promise.reject. So, the rejection handler that the catch method registers is for the promise returned by the then method. So the only way the catch method will be invoked is if the then method promise is rejected.
But in the code example above, the rejection of the original promise (Promise.reject()) is handled by the rejection handler registered using the two-argument then method call. So, in this case, then method's promise isn't rejected, so the catch method callback is never called.

If it handles the error or you call Promise.resolve(), then the Promise switches back to fulfilled state

Promise state cannot be changed once it is settled, i.e. either fulfilled or rejected.
If you handle the error in the catch method callback, i.e., you don't throw an error or a rejected promise, or a promise that will ultimately be rejected, then the promise returned by the catch method will be fulfilled.
Note that the original promise is still rejected. It is the catch method's promise that is fulfilled.

If it rethrows the errors or you call Promise.reject() it will propogate the error, promise stays in the rejection state and it will look for the closest catch method.

In this case, the promise returned by the catch method will be rejected. The original promise is unaffected. It will stay in its state, regardless of what you do inside the catch method callback.

So my question is - how can we simple exit / terminate the Promise process from either then or catch callbacks

Generally speaking, you have catch method calls at the end of the promise chain, but if you have a catch method call in-between the promise chain, then you most likely want to handle the rejection and continue the promise chain.
Only way to prevent then method callbacks from executing that are chained after the catch method call is to reject the promise returned by the catch method.

...if we end up in this "callback hell" scenario?

You have a linear promise chain. Following is what you would refer to as a "callback hell":
callback1(result1, function(result2, callback2) {
    callback2(result2, function(result3, callback3) {
       callback3(result3, function(result4, callback4) {
          // and so on...
       });
    });
});


So if I have catch method and it's not the last one in the chain, there is no way to "stop" Promise from going to the next method, because it will either be "fulfilled (goes to then) or it will be refected (goes to catch). Also I would never use the then method with both callbacks (linear method as you mentioned, but simplified version -> then(fulfillCallback, rejectCallback), because if the fulfil callback throws an error, it would be not handled. Thanks for spending the time and the reply!

No, you cannot stop the promise fulfillment or rejection from propagating through the entire promise chain. However, you can skip some code inside the then callback from executing as explained in this comment

"I would never use the then method with both callbacks (linear method as you mentioned, but simplified version -> then(fulfillCallback, rejectCallback), because if the fulfil callback throws an error, it would be not handled" - It is only useful if you want to handle the rejection of the promise on which then method is called and continue the promise chain. However, this could also be achieved using the catch method. I used it to show that promise rejection cannot jump directly to the nearest catch method. Instead, it goes through the promise chain until it reaches a rejection handler.

Got ya, very much appreciated!

Just a suggestion: maybe a more accessible way to illustrate the initial chaining thing would be to actually unchain it and use something like p2 = p1.then(...)? So that the first .catch() is clearly p2.catch() and the next one is p5.catch()?
